# serve required styles only CSS

Tags: asp.net, css, optimization

Is there a way of filtering large CSS files for the only required selectors on a page, and creating css files that contain just these selectors?

Case: I have a very large CSS file that I want to filter on a per page basis, so that the file size is cut down and can be cached by mobile devices. I was thinking along the lines of something like a server side [dust me selectors](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/5392/) tool.

The particular project I am working on is using ASP.NET MVC.

Thanks

Comment: In the case of mobile caching, better to download one larger file once, than many smaller ones per page with duplicated code.

Comment: @Terw Not if the filesize is so big it won't be cached at all (according to this http://www.phpied.com/iphone-caching/).

Comment: What's the size of your CSS file?

Comment: @Marko 200k, site is ridiculously large

Comment: wow...10k limit? That's a tough one. That said, read the article...the solution may be to leverage HTML5's application cache.

Comment: who...200k css files? Yikes. Based on my answer below, the real fix may be to get the CSS rethought/rewritten.

Comment: Maybe a crazy/dumb idea, but what if mobile browsers got served 20 individual 10k files instead? Would they all be cached?

Comment: Really, you should look into making an own mobile version. It's expensive for your visitors to visit your page, + it would take years to load it.

Comment: I agree with Terw ^^ and wouldn't necessary use a "tool" to do the "selecting". Instead, I would rewrite the CSS into components that get used on different pages and only load them where they get used. However you weigh it, 200kb CSS + images + html and any Javascript would be a mobile nightmare. You could build all your pages, then maybe spend a day in Firebug determining what CSS rules are being applied and copy those over to a new mobile.css stylesheet. There's a lot of 'dependencies' when it comes to CSS selectors for any framework to do your job effectively. P.S. Consider GZIPping.

Answer (score 0):

Heads up that while you might get smaller individual page loads, the overall load of browsing the site will be higher given that you're hitting the server each and every time for a new CSS file (rather than just caching a site-level CSS file once).

In addition, if you find that there are a lot of unique per-page CSS declarations, the CSS for the site may not be written very well. So the solution may be to go back and rethink the CSS structure to begin with, perhaps looking into OOCSS models:

http://wiki.github.com/stubbornella/oocss/

Unfortunately, none of that answers your specific question.

Comment: good advice, I'd love to rewrite all the css but time is a factor too, thanks!